# Hybrid Systemn Anomalous results while using ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

> ```
> The hybrid system that I am solving
> ```

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.8 bounce[t], 
        y[0] == height, y'[0] == 0, bounce[0] == 1, 
        WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, 
         If[Abs[y'[t]] > 10^-6, 
          y'[t] -> -0.7 y'[t], {bounce[t], y'[t]} -> {0, 0}]]}, 
       y[t], {t, 0, 4}, {height}, DiscreteVariables -> bounce];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[height], {height, 1, 5, .2}]], {t, 0, 4},PlotRange -> All]
```

Result
[image: First run, result]

Then I run the following:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun'[height], {height, 1, 5, .2}]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Result:
[image: Sensitivity]

Now I rerun

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[height], {height, 1, 5, .2}]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

to get
[image: New simulation]

Why are these results different. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try your second picture with this command:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[D[pfun[height], t], {height, 1, 5, .2}]], {t, 0,4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Then repeating the first plot givse the same picture as it was:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[height], {height, 1, 5, .2}]], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what makes this different?

Comment: `pfun'` means take derivative w.r.t. parameter, i.e. `height` in your case.I supposed you want to see dependance of derivative on time, so I changed this to explicit differenciation w.r.t. time `t`. I don't understand what's going on when you take derivative w.r.t. parameter, MMA somehow changes `pfun` after that. The same effect can be seen if you just take `pfun'[1]`, then repeat first `Plot`---it changed. I think you better ask Wolfram support, probably this is a bug or misunderstanding.

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. But, No, I actually want the derivative with respect to the parameter height varied as a function of time.That is,  (pfun' w.r.t height)[t] as a function of time.